# ttk.Style not working although ttk does run my commands

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to edit the style of my program using ttk.Style, so I wrote this

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
        self.root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.theme = ttk.Style()
        self.theme.theme_use('clam')
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Test')
        self.button.pack()
```

Yet when I run the code, nothing changes. I printed theme_use() and the theme is clam like I set, yet nothing happens. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You aren’t using any ttk widgets. The style only affects ttk widgets.

Comment: Is there a tkinter equivalent? @Bryan Oakley

Comment: @SnivyDroid: tkinter equivalent to styles? ttk is the tkinter equivalent. If you want to use styles, use ttk widgets whenever possible.

Comment: Alright then. If I use a combination of ttk and tkinter elements (spinboxes and intvars are not supported), will that affect anything? @Bryan Oakley. If not how deep can customizable go in tkinter so I can remove the pretty ugly style of most elements?

Comment: @SnivyDroid: answers to all these questions can be found with just a little experimentation.